# Как распределить карточки в контейнере равномерно одну за другой

Tags: html, css

На странице сайта делаю блок с карточками, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытаюсь их выровнять блоком, они остаются совмещены одна на другой, как их разделить и при этом распределить по всей ширине блока?

Выглядит это сейчас примерно так https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWl4n.png

Также ниже прикрепляю код

HTML

```
                    <div className="card">
                        <img/>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card_1">
                        <img/>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card_2">
                        <img/>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card_3">
                        <img/>
                        <div className="container">
                            <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS

````
principal .card_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    bottom: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}

principal .card {
    background: #ebebeb;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;

}

principal .card_1 {
    background: #ebebeb;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

principal .card_2 {
    background: #ebebeb;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

principal .card_3 {
    background: #ebebeb;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

principal .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPvrF.png
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё проще чем вы думаете

```css
.principal {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  margin: 24px;
  padding: 24px 12px;
}

.container h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="principal">
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>Second line</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img/>
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>HTML CSS</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```